# Pandas counter that counts by skipping a row and reset on different values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, counter

Hi I am trying to create a counter that counts my trend column by skipping a row and reset itself if the string values are different. For example on row 9 it will count 2 since the previous skipped row it was counted with a 1. But it resets back to one since the value at row 11 is different from row 9.
Is there anyway I could do this?

```
DateTimeStarted         50% Quantile    50Q shift 2H    Trend    Count
0   2020-12-18 15:00:00 554.0           NaN             Flat     1
1   2020-12-18 16:00:00 593.0           NaN             Flat     1
2   2020-12-18 17:00:00 534.0           554.0           Down     1
3   2020-12-18 18:00:00 562.0           593.0           Down     1
4   2020-12-18 19:00:00 552.0           534.0           Up       1
5   2020-12-18 20:00:00 592.0           562.0           Up       1
6   2020-12-19 08:00:00 511.0           552.0           Down     1
7   2020-12-19 09:00:00 584.0           592.0           Down     1
8   2020-12-19 10:00:00 576.0           511.0           Up       1
9   2020-12-19 11:00:00 545.5           584.0           Down     2
10  2020-12-19 12:00:00 609.5           576.0           Up       2
11  2020-12-19 13:00:00 548.0           545.5           Up       1
12  2020-12-19 14:00:00 565.0           609.5           Down     1
13  2020-12-19 15:00:00 575.0           548.0           Up       2
14  2020-12-19 16:00:00 570.0           565.0           Up       1
15  2020-12-19 17:00:00 557.0           575.0           Down     1 
16  2020-12-19 18:00:00 578.0           570.0           Up       2
17  2020-12-19 19:00:00 578.5           557.0           Up       1
18  2020-12-21 08:00:00 543.0           578.0           Down     1
19  2020-12-21 09:00:00 558.0           578.5           Down     1
20  2020-12-21 10:00:00 570.0           543.0           Up       1
```

Comment: Is this current `Count` column your desired output? It seems like there are a lot of `Trend` transitions that didn't create `Count` changes, so I don't quite understand.

Comment: yes this is the desired output

Comment: Why doesn't `Count` change for index 2 (`Flat`->`Down`) or index 4 (`Down`->`Up`), index 6, etc?

Comment: no its suppose to count by skipping 1 row. so for index 4 comparing index 6 if its a (Up -> Up) then it will increase the count to 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`shift()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) the `Trend` column by 2 and check if it equals `Trend`:

```py
df['Counter'] = df.Trend.shift(2).eq(df.Trend).astype(int).add(1)
```

I named it `Counter` here for comparison:

```
        DateTimeStarted  50%Quantile  50Qshift2H Trend  Count  Counter
0   2020-12-18 15:00:00        554.0         NaN  Flat      1        1
1   2020-12-18 16:00:00        593.0         NaN  Flat      1        1
2   2020-12-18 17:00:00        534.0       554.0  Down      1        1
3   2020-12-18 18:00:00        562.0       593.0  Down      1        1
4   2020-12-18 19:00:00        552.0       534.0    Up      1        1
5   2020-12-18 20:00:00        592.0       562.0    Up      1        1
6   2020-12-19 08:00:00        511.0       552.0  Down      1        1
7   2020-12-19 09:00:00        584.0       592.0  Down      1        1
8   2020-12-19 10:00:00        576.0       511.0    Up      1        1
9   2020-12-19 11:00:00        545.5       584.0  Down      2        2
10  2020-12-19 12:00:00        609.5       576.0    Up      2        2
11  2020-12-19 13:00:00        548.0       545.5    Up      1        1
12  2020-12-19 14:00:00        565.0       609.5  Down      1        1
13  2020-12-19 15:00:00        575.0       548.0    Up      2        2
14  2020-12-19 16:00:00        570.0       565.0    Up      1        1
15  2020-12-19 17:00:00        557.0       575.0  Down      1        1
16  2020-12-19 18:00:00        578.0       570.0    Up      2        2
17  2020-12-19 19:00:00        578.5       557.0    Up      1        1
18  2020-12-21 08:00:00        543.0       578.0  Down      1        1
19  2020-12-21 09:00:00        558.0       578.5  Down      1        1
20  2020-12-21 10:00:00        570.0       543.0    Up      1        1
```

Comment: Yes its correct. I initially used this code but didn't turn out well.
df['Count'] = df.groupby((df['Trend'] != df['Trend'].shift(2)).cumsum()).cumcount()+1